# Sprite Kit setting a nodes angle (not rotate)

Tags: ios, sprite, sprite-kit, angle, sknode

Okay so I have a game that the player(space ship) is trying to go around a planet, but if it gets to close the player's space ship is turned to the planet.

So I am trying to use:

```
float dx = [_player position].x - [planetNodes[i] position].x;
float dy = [_player position].y - [planetNodes[i] position].y;
double angleToTurn = (180.0 / M_PI)  * atan2(dy, dx);
NSLog(@"Turn to: %f", angleToTurn);
_player.zRotation = angleToTurn;
```

This code is put in the update method of the scene. Whenever the player gets too close to the planet it begins spinning because I am using the rotate method. Is there a method like setAngle? That way whenever the update is called it will reset the angle and actually look like the player is moving towards the planet.

Comment: the atan2 function was the key for me. I could not figure out how to calculate the rotation across all quadrants of a positive coordinate system. atan alone was not working.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `zRotation` property correctly.  Setting that property will have the desired effect, the problem is that you are giving `_player.zRotation` a value in *degrees* when you should be giving it *radians*.  As the player approaches the planet, the angle changes, and the player rotates 180/pi times faster than it should because you are multiplying the angle by that.

What you want is:

```
angleToTurn = atan2(dy,dx);
```

Instead of

```
angleToTurn = (180.0 / M_PI) * atan2(dy,dx);
```

Answer (score 1):

to make rotation to angle use

```
        [_player runAction:[SKAction rotateToAngle:atan2(dy, dx) duration:0.0 shortestUnitArc:YES]]
```

the sprite movement will be animated and look much nicer then just setting the zRotation.

note: the function takes radians, so no need to convert to degrees.